# Artin-Tate chow motives and graded Galois representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, tate-motives

Consider the category $\mathsf{Chow}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ of rational pure effective chow $k$-motives. The full subcategory of Artin motives (generated by (X,p,0), X smooth projective zero-dimensional, let $k$ with $char(k)=0$ for simplicity) is equivalent to the category of Galois representations (over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Is it true that the full subcategory of Artin-Tate motives (we add Tate motive $\mathbb{Q}(-1)$ and its powers) is equivalent to the category of *graded* Galois representations ?

Comment: Yes; this is true.:)

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Thank you. Now, I understand that my question was a bit misleading, since in general Tate motive is a bit different notion than Lefschetz motive. May be this subcategory of Chow motives is better to call Artin-Lefschetz motives. But I have a bit different question now:

Is it true that K_0(Artin-Lefschetz) embedded in K_0(Chow_Q) ?

Comment: It does, since obvious embedding of $K_0(AT)\to K_0(Mot_{num})$ (the categories are semi-simple!) factors through  $K_0(AT)\to K_0(Chow)$.